# Cassandra: Resolution of concurrent schema changes

Tags: cassandra

I have been unable to find information on how Cassandra handles concurrent changes to its schema. For example:

In Cassandra cluster with machines A,B,C,D,E

Client X issues to machine A:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id_column int,
  x_column1 varchar,
  x_column2 varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_column)
)
```

Client Y issues to machine B

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  id_column int,
  y_another_column1 varchar,
  y_another_column2 varchar,
  PRIMARY KEY (id_column)
)
```

What happens? Does it fail? Is the final result a merge of both? If it is a merge, would it fail if diff PKs columns had been chosen?

I guess concurrent creation of conflicting schema is an unusual scenario. However issuing concurrent ALTER TABLE statements would need similar resolution and that more likely in a real world scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following 2 posts and 2 JIRA tickets (resolved) provide details about live schema changes and conflict resolution:

- [Live schema updates](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-live-schema-updates) (*nb*: the version applies to when this feature was firstly available)
- [The schema management renaissance in Cassandra 1.1](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-schema-management-renaissance).
- [Allow concurrent schema migrations (1391)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1391) (fixed in C* 1.1)
- [Avoid ID conflicts from concurrent schema changes (3794)](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-3794) (fixed in C* 1.2)

You'll have to go through the comments in [CASSANDRA-1391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-1391) to get all the details.

Comment: Thanks, this is enough to get going with. I'll try digest this and summarize into an answer for others.

Comment: The reason I didn't summarize it myself is that there are nuances and reading those sources will provide enough details.