# Is the schema synchronized immediately when you run a CQL CREATE TABLE command in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, thrift, cql

When I first started with Cassandra, I used thrift.

After creating a table, I had to wait to make sure the table was created on all nodes. Without a wait, a node may not be ready and the table would not be usable (many errors would be emitted if the query was sent to "the wrong node".)

In order to "synchronized", I would wait until `describe_schema_versions()` returned exactly one version of the schema. That meant it was frozen on all nodes.

There does not seem to be an equivalent in CQL. Does that mean that the synchronization problem of older versions (with Thrift) was fixed? Or did I miss something in my searches?

Answer (score 4):

In CQL since Cassandra 1.1 when you do a schema change your coordinator node does all of the heavy lifting to ensure that the schema is "synchronized". And if there's a node down during the schema change, before it comes up again it makes sure it has the latest schema version from the other nodes.[More Detailed Information about the change from the old way here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/the-schema-management-renaissance). Here's another related [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293897/cassandra-resolution-of-concurrent-schema-changes) about how to resolve schema conflicts.

Comment: This sounds strange though, because with thrift, even in Cassandra 2.x, I still had to do that synchronization. From what I'm reading, it should not have been required since the schema is handled at a high level in the Cassandra system...

Answer (score 4):

The modern DataStax drivers automatically check and wait for schema agreement after you execute a schema-altering statement.  Cassandra returns a special response for schema-altering statements that allows the drivers to do this automatically.  Once the drivers gets that response, it (blockingly) queries the `system.peers` table of the node the query was executed against to check the reported schema versions of other nodes.  It will continue to execute this query in a loop until either schema agreement is reached or a timeout is hit.

In the Python driver, if a timeout is hit without reaching schema agreement, the `ResponseFuture` object (that's returned from `execute_async()`) will have its `is_schema_agreed` property set to `False`.  I'm not sure what the drivers for other languages do, but there's probably something similar available.

To summarize, the checks that you used to have to do with Thrift drivers are now automatic, and probably more robust.

Comment: Ah! That actually makes sense. That means my thrift loop was indeed still necessary. We use C++ here, but I would imagine that the driver does something similar so one can know whether the schema is in place as expected.

Comment: Sorry but this is really not practical since if it times out you cannot access the table. This new CQL stuff is really useless.